# Clustering data in a file

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file in the following format

```
--
752721  1
757734  1
757936  1
758144  1
758324  1
--
842825  1
843940  1
--
1301199 1
--
--
1302408 1
1302555 1
--
--
--
--
1306558 1
1307638 1
1308628 1
```

The '--' is a delimiter. I want to cluster these entries together like this:

```
752721 - 758324 5
842825 - 843940 2
1301199 1
1302408 - 1302555 2
1306558 - 1308628 3
```

where the range of a cluster is displayed and the count of the number of elements in it are appended next to the range.

I tried few options in awk and sed. Somehow they didn't work out. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Concrete questions about what went wrong with your awk code are on topic, but listing a task and multiple languages you're willing to accept code isn't, really.  Right now there's not really a question to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code which reads from stdin (or a filename passed as the first command line argument):

```
import fileinput

def report(first,last,count):
  if first == last:
    print first, count
  else:
    print first, "-", last, count

first = None
last = None
count = 0
for line in fileinput.input():
  line = line.strip()
  if line == "--":
    if last:
      report(first, last, count)
    last = first = None
    count = 0
  else:
    words = line.split()
    i = words[0]
    n = int(words[1])
    if not first:
      first = i
      count = 0
    last = i
    count = count + n
if first:
  report(first, last, count)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk 'function out(){if (count>0)printf "%s - %s %s\n",first,last,count;count=0}; /--/{out()} NF<2 {next} count==0{first=$1} {last=$1;count+=1} END{out()}' file2
752721 - 758324 5
842825 - 843940 2
1301199 - 1301199 1
1302408 - 1302555 2
1306558 - 1308628 3
```

#### How it works

This code uses three variables.  `first` and `last` denote the range and `count` is the number of lines found in that range.

- `function out(){if (count>0)printf "%s - %s %s\n",first,last,count;count=0}`

  This defines a function `out` which, if there is a cluster to be printed, that is if `count>0`, prints the cluster.
- `/--/{out()}`

  Every time we reach a delimiter, call function `out` to print out any cluster data.
- `NF<2 {next}`

  If this is an empty line or a delimiter line, skip the rest of the commands and jump to the next line
- `count==0{first=$1}`

  If this is the first line of a cluster, set `first`.
- `{last=$1;count+=1}`

  Update `last` and `count`.
- `END{out()}`

  At the end of the file, print the data for the last cluster.

### Refinement

This version matches the desired output more closely.  It does not print "first - last" when `first` and `last` are the same:

```
$ awk 'function out(){if (count>0){printf "%s ",first; if(first!=last)printf"- %s ",last; print count;count=0}}; /--/{out()} NF<2 {next} count==0{first=$1} {last=$1;count+=1} END{out()}' file
752721 - 758324 5
842825 - 843940 2
1301199 1
1302408 - 1302555 2
1306558 - 1308628 3
```

This is accomplished by changing the logic in the `out` function to:

```
function out(){
    if (count>0){
        printf "%s ",first
        if(first!=last)
            printf"- %s ",last; 
        print count;count=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's why i like awk, simple, short and efficient

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('/path/to/output') as infile:
    buffer = []
    for line in infile:
        line = line.split()[0]
        if line == '--':
            if buffer:
                print("{} - {} {}".format(buffer[0], buffer[-1], len(buffer)))
                buffer = []
        else:
            buffer.append(int(line))
    if buffer:
        print("{} - {} {}".format(buffer[0], buffer[-1], len(buffer)))
```

Output:

```
752721 - 758324 5
842825 - 843940 2
1301199 - 1301199 1
1302408 - 1302555 2
1306558 - 1308628 3
```